# Can I create a website similar to SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, legal, clone

Can I copy Stack Overflow design, layout and color combination to create a new website?

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638/which-cms-or-other-framework-should-i-use-to-develop-a-stackoverflow-like-site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**site design and logo is © 2009 stackoverflow.com llc**